# FFMPEG is doubling audio length when extracting from video

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a video file, `video.mp4`. It is 18 minutes 23 seconds in duration. I am looking to extract the *audio only* from this video, and create an MP3 of the highest possible quality from the audio in the video.

Some googlefu lead me to this command: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 audio.mp3`

The problem is that, this command **doubles** the length of the audio that's outputted (duration is 36 minutes 46 seconds). It loops the audio track once, so the output contains the entire 18 minutes 23 seconds of audio, then immediately starts the 18 minutes and 23 seconds of audio over again.

Some more googlefu lead me to this flag: `-write_xing 0` from [this SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/607703/wrong-audio-duration-with-ffmpeg), but even with that flag it still loops the audio.

**EDIT**: Additional googlefu and me seeming to think it has something to do with 2 audio channels (and perhaps looping channel 2 immediately after channel 1, rather than merging the two) lead me to this flag: `-ac 1` to force it to merge stereo -> mono. This did not work also, and it still outputs a 38 minute 46 seconds MP3 file.

How can I extract (to MP3) the audio from a video file, without doubling the duration?

Comment: Cross posting the [same question](http://superuser.com/questions/892996/ffmpeg-is-doubling-audio-length-when-extracting-from-video) on multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged, and this question is off topic here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your googlefu must be malfunctioning.

If you have a single audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -map 0:a -c:a mp3 audio.mp3
```

If you have multiple audio tracks:

1. Identify the track:

`ffprobe -i movie.mp4` and look for an audio **Stream #0:x** where `x` is an integer

2. Use the above command using `-map 0:x`. Example for `x = 2`:

`ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -map 0:2 -c:a mp3 audio.mp3`

[How to use the -map option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20use%20-map%20option)